# PC-BSD command line approaches to sleep (suspend to RAM) and hibernate (suspend to disk)

Tags: freebsd, suspend, pc-bsd

### Background

Lumina offers a *Suspend* option, which works.

KDE Plasma 4 offers *Sleep* and *Hibernate* options, neither of which work.

As suspend to RAM can work with Lumina, so I'd like to try the same with KDE.

### The question

Are there command-line approaches to sleep (suspend to RAM) and hibernate (suspend to disk)?

#### Software

[PC-BSD](http://www.pcbsd.org/) 11.0-CURRENTMAR2016 (based on FreeBSD) with [upower](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/upower/) and [Lumina](http://lumina-desktop.org/) release 0.8.8_2,1.

```
[graham@macbookpro82] ~% pkg -v upower
1.6.4
[graham@macbookpro82]
```

…

```
[graham@macbookpro82] ~% pkg info lumina                                                                                                                                                                   
lumina-0.8.8_2,1                                                                                                                                                                                           
Name           : lumina                                                                                                                                                                                    
Version        : 0.8.8_2,1                                                                                                                                                                                 
Installed on   : Wed Mar  9 13:31:37 2016 GMT                                                                                                                                                              
Origin         : x11/lumina                                                                                                                                                                                
Architecture   : freebsd:11:x86:64                                                                                                                                                                         
Prefix         : /usr/local
Categories     : x11
Licenses       : BSD3CLAUSE
Maintainer     : kmoore@FreeBSD.org
WWW            : http://lumina-desktop.org
Comment        : Lumina Desktop Environment
Options        :
        MULTIMEDIA     : on
        PCBSD          : on
Shared Libs required:
        libxcb-composite.so.0
        libxcb-damage.so.0
        libQt5X11Extras.so.5
        libQt5Gui.so.5
        libQt5Core.so.5
        libxcb-ewmh.so.2
        libGL.so.1
        libXdamage.so.1
        libxcb-image.so.0
        libQt5Concurrent.so.5
        libQt5Widgets.so.5
        libxcb-util.so.1
        libQt5Network.so.5
        libxcb-icccm.so.4
        libQt5Multimedia.so.5
        libQt5Svg.so.5
        libxcb.so.1
        libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5
Shared Libs provided:
        libLuminaUtils.so.1
Annotations    :
        icon           : \"http://www.pcbsd.org/appcafe/icons/x11_lumina.png\"
        repo_type      : binary
        repository     : pcbsd-major
        screen1        : \"http://www.pcbsd.org/appcafe/screenshots/x11/lumina/screen1.png\"
Flat size      : 11.8MiB
Description    :
Lumina-DE is a lightweight, BSD licensed desktop environment,
designed specifically for use on FreeBSD

WWW: http://lumina-desktop.org
[graham@macbookpro82] ~%
```

KDE

```
[graham@macbookpro82] ~% pkg info pcbsd-meta-kde
pcbsd-meta-kde-1429798531
Name           : pcbsd-meta-kde
Version        : 1429798531
Installed on   : Wed Mar  9 14:25:06 2016 GMT
Origin         : misc/pcbsd-meta-kde
Architecture   : freebsd:11:x86:64
Prefix         : /usr/local
Categories     : misc
Licenses       : 
Maintainer     : kris@pcbsd.org
WWW            : http://www.pcbsd.org
Comment        : The meta-port pcbsd-meta-kde
Annotations    :
        icon           : \"http://www.pcbsd.org/appcafe/icons/misc_pcbsd-meta-kde.png\"
        repo_type      : binary
        repository     : pcbsd-major
        screen1        : \"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/KDE_4.png/1024px-KDE_4.png\"
Flat size      : 0.00B
Description    :
The meta-port for PC-BSD meta-pkg kde

WWW: http://www.pcbsd.org
[graham@macbookpro82] ~%
```

#### Hardware

Apple notebook, early 2011 MacBookPro8,2

- [MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP620)
- [MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.0 15" Early 2011 Specs (Early 2011 15", MC721LL/A, MacBookPro8,2, A1286, 2353-1*) @ EveryMac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.0-15-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html)

It's currently **without a battery**, so hibernation is particularly desirable. (If I can get sleep or hibernation to work with KDE Plasma 4 on PC-BSD, then I'll arrange a replacement battery.)

### Notes

```
[graham@macbookpro82] ~% pkg search power | grep manage
gnome-power-manager-3.18.0     Power management system for the GNOME Desktop
mate-power-manager-1.12.1      Power management system for the MATE Desktop
upower-0.99.3                  D-Bus daemon for simplifying power management tasks                                                                                                                         
xfce4-power-manager-1.5.2      Power manager for the Xfce Desktop                                                                                                                                          
[graham@macbookpro82] ~% pkg search suspend                                                                                                                                                                
p5-Thread-Suspend-1.22_1       Suspend and resume operations for threads                                                                                                                                   
[graham@macbookpro82] ~% pkg search sleep                                                                                                                                                                  
vdr-plugin-sleeptimer-0.8.2_5  Video Disk Recorder - sleep timer plugin                                                                                                                                    
[graham@macbookpro82] ~% pkg search hibernat
[graham@macbookpro82] ~% freebsd-version ; uname -a                                                                                                                                                        
11.0-CURRENTMAR2016                                                                                                                                                                                        
FreeBSD macbookpro82 11.0-CURRENTMAR2016 FreeBSD 11.0-CURRENTMAR2016 #0 e0cb0b6(freebsd-base-graphics): Sat Feb 27 01:01:50 UTC 2016     root@devastator:/usr/obj/tmp/build/80Wd/pcb                       sd/git/freebsd/sys/GENERIC  amd64                                                                                                                                                                          
[graham@macbookpro82] ~%
```

FreeBSD 10.2 manual pages:

- [upower(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=upower&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports)
- [UPower(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=UPower&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports)

Comment: Maybe https://wiki.freebsd.org/SuspendResume will help on how to use the CLI on FreeBSD or derivatives for suspend/resume.

Answer (score 1):

### [SuspendResume - FreeBSD Wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/SuspendResume) (Suspend/Resume – 2014-10-06)

Thanks to @schaiba for the hint.

#### [acpiconf(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=acpiconf&sektion=8)

Option `-h` does not work as described in the manual page –

```
$ date ; freebsd-version ; uname -a
13 March 2016 at 15:29:23 GMT
11.0-CURRENTMAR2016
FreeBSD macbookpro82 11.0-CURRENTMAR2016 FreeBSD 11.0-CURRENTMAR2016 #0 e0cb0b6(freebsd-base-graphics): Sat Feb 27 01:01:50 UTC 2016     root@devastator:/usr/obj/tmp/build/80Wd/pcbsd/git/freebsd/sys/GENERIC  amd64
$ acpiconf -h
usage: acpiconf [-h] [-i batt] [-k ack] [-s 1-4]
$
```

– but sleep mode 3 can be tested:

> … the CPU context is lost and memory context is preserved …

The wiki directs users to test without X.

It's also possible to test whilst the X Window System runs so, for example, in a terminal window:

`sudo acpiconf -s 3`

If, following sleep, the resumed screen is illegible, a press of the power button may perform an ACPI shut down.

#### Hibernation

My test of sleep mode 4 with a MacBookPro8,2 effectively stopped the computer, with no resume, but according to the wiki that's expected with FreeBSD:

> … We don't yet have the necessary infrastructure in place to make suspend to disk work on amd64 or i386. …

---

### The FreeBSD Laptop Compatibility List

Linked from the Suspend/Resume page in the FreeBSD wiki, but no longer served from https://laptop.bsdgroup.de/freebsd/index.html

At http://web.archive.org/web/20130705054229/http://laptop.bsdgroup.de/freebsd/index.html some of the compatibility list content is archived. Not all – for example, of the [three listings for Apple products](http://web.archive.org/web/20130625205839/http://laptop.bsdgroup.de/freebsd/index.html?action=list_laptop_mf&mfid=1961), two of the linked pages are not archived.

Comment: KDE Plasma 4 on PC-BSD 11.0-CURRENTMAR2016: following `acpiconf -s 3` in vty 2, sleep then resume produces a KDE screen that is illegible.